# Add VBA code in order to amend Excel output in SSIS before sending to Excel destination?

Tags: ssis

I have a current package which basically copies an Excel template sheet, writes data into this from a table in the SQL database and then sends to Excel destination (ishare drive and server drives). We have repeated rows with specific data which need to be removed from the Excel sheet before it is sent out. We have a VBA code which can be run in Excel as a macro in order to achieve this result. I am wondering how I can automate this in SSIS in the data flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a current package which basically copies a an excel template
> sheet, writes data into this from a table in the sql db

You can use a Data Flow Task where you import data from the SQL Server database:
Create a connection manager :
[image]

When you click on the New Connection Manager option, an Add SSIS Connection Manager window form will open to select the connections managers from the given list.
[image]

Then select the Provider, Server Name, and Database Name (you will point to a SQL Server database you can either select the table or use a query)

- If you want to remove duplicate entries you can use Drag  Transformation and Connect your OLE DB Source to it. Double Click on Sort Transformation and Choose the columns to Sort. Also Check the Check Box : Remove rows with duplicate sort values and then click OK.
- If you have other specific rules, you can implement a T-SQL query when importing data from the begining (when using the OLE DB Source)

Then you can link it to an Excel destination.